# Rails - Multiple Routes For Many to One Relationship collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

RubyonRails - 4.x version with mongoDb.

So i have a Area Page as the top level class. It has_many Parks and Houses.
I am trying to have CRUD operations for both Parks and Houses from the same Area UI page. So Area index page would have 2 add buttons(ADD Park & ADD House). Index page for Area should also show all the parks and houses with each of them having their own EDIT and DELETE buttons.

I am unsure how to setup the routes/controllers/views and their folder structure.

```
class Area
   has_many :parks, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Parks
   belongs_to :area
end

class Houses
   belongs_to :area
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a basic route configuration:

```
resources :areas do
  resources :parks
  resources :houses
end
```

The thing is, with this configuration, the ParksController and HousesController will be in the same folder as AreasController. If you want a subdirectory named `areas` containing the two controllers, just do:

```
resources :areas do
  scope module: :areas do
    resources :parks
    resources :houses
  end
end
```

And you will end up with folder structure like this:

```
app/
  controllers/
    areas/
      parks_controller.rb
      houses_controller.rb
    areas_controller.rb
  views/
    areas/
      areas/
        parks/
        houses/
      index.html.haml
      edit.html.haml
      # etc. (views for AreasController actions)
```

Comment: thanks. I will try to work with this solution and report back